# how to deal with dependency in Java

Tags: java, android, dependencies

I am very new to `Android`, I have to install some dependency, and the doc says

> You will need to include the dagger-${dagger.version}.jar in your
>   application's runtime. In order to activate code generation you will
>   need to include dagger-compiler-${dagger.version}.jar in your build at
>   compile time.

But, my project is not a `Maven` one. How can I do that ?

Comment: put the jar inside libs/ (if you do not have it, you have to create it). Android will do the rest

Comment: @blackbelt that's what I wanted to do but the dagger download doesn't provide any jar, see here: https://github.com/square/dagger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to download the pre-built jars directly and put them in your libs directory.  From the Dagger page

> You can also find downloadable .jars on Maven Central. You'll need Dagger, JavaWriter, and javax.inject

Here are the relevant links

- [Dagger](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22com.squareup.dagger%22%20a%3a%22dagger%22)
- [JavaWriter](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22com.squareup%22%20a%3a%22javawriter%22)
- [javax.inject](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22javax.inject%22%20a%3a%22javax.inject%22)

Just click on the jar links to download the jars you need.

Comment: I have imported those as you mentioned but I still get `import javax.inject.Inject;` (and such imports) shows error. Should I put `javax.inject.jar` instead of `javax.inject-1.jar` ?

Comment: The file `javax.inject-1.jar` should work fine.  Are you sure it is added to your classpath?

Comment: ah no in fact, it was my ice that took some times to recognize it ! Thank you ! Btw, could explain what is the difference between `run time` and `compile time` dependency ?

Comment: A run time dependency is something that needs to be present on the classpath when an application is run.  For example, an implementation of an API.  A compile time dependency is something that is needed by the compiler to compile some code.  This would be the API itself.